# Условие $gt для элементов массива

Tags: массивы, mongodb, pymongo, nosql, база-данных

Всем привет и сразу к вопросу:
Представим следующий документ в базе mongodb

```
{
    'myarray': [
        {'key': 1}
    ]
}
{
    'myarray': [
        {'key': 2}
    ]
}
```

Как я могу выбрать документы где key в myarray больше единицы?
Запись вида myarray.key не работает. Если есть возможность не использовать $where, то такой вариант был бы идеальным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все работает

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53b9f1c58a553075f4ae81fc"), "array" : [ { "key" : 1 }, { "key" : 10 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53b9f1cb8a553075f4ae81fd"), "array" : [ { "key" : 1 }, { "key" : 100 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53b9f1d18a553075f4ae81fe"), "array" : [ { "key" : 1000 }, { "key" : 100 } ] }
```

Выборка

```
db.test.find( { "array.key": { "$gt": 25 } } );
```

Результат

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53b9f1cb8a553075f4ae81fd"), "array" : [ { "key" : 1 }, { "key" : 100 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53b9f1d18a553075f4ae81fe"), "array" : [ { "key" : 1000 }, { "key" : 100 } ] }
```

Comment: думал что такую форму записи не понимает pymongo, но на вашем примере работает. буду благодарен если кто-то подскажет альтернативный вариант для проверки, а @webphp спасибо.

Comment: да, все работает верно. проблема была в том, что я ожидал одного, а приходило другое, но приходило таким верно.